# Dynamically update a Metro listView upon horizontal scroll (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, listview, microsoft-metro

In the following code:

```
            var dataObj = document.getElementById("listView").winControl;
            var postList = new WinJS.Binding.List(appData); //json formatted data array
            var filteredList = postList.createFiltered(function _filterItems(item) { return item.ID < 3 });
        dataObj.itemDataSource = filteredList.dataSource;
```

I create a filtered list which only displays the first 3 items.
I'd like to dynamically add more items as i scroll sideways,

What's the proper way of achieving this?

Comment: You shouldn't use signatures as all your posts are already properly signed with your user card. Take a read at the [Can I use a signature or tagline?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) part of the FAQ. `:)`

Comment: Thanks man, won't happen again =]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the appData is coming from, this may or may not be overkill

How to create a custom data source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770849.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jeff,
However, eventually, i've implemented a simple view controller using js - one that cerate another list item when the previous one gets outside the screen.
I've attached it to the mousewheel/scroll events and it works.
Creating custom data sources isn't really the issue, but the rendering is.
Metro still lakes basic element states which you need to hack through in order to implement.